# Group By month with sum value and rolling year

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I'm trying to group sales data by month in MySQL but with a rolling year sum value.
Example expected output:

```
Month                           SUM
January 2018    Total from february 2017 to january 2018 (12months)
February 2018   Total from march 2017 to february 2018 (12months)
...
```

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT YEAR(date), MONTH(date), 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tb t2 WHERE t2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND t1.date)
FROM tb t1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

The results are those expected but this is highly inefficient as it takes 30seconds to run if I use an interval of 3days (so I can't even run it with the 1 year interval)

Any ideas how to improve this query so I can use a 1 year interval ? Is an index needed on a specific field ?

**Edit**:
Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb` (
  `inc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quantity` float NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inc`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

It has more than 100k rows and I can't upgrade to MySQL >= 8

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If you can upgrade to MySQL version >= 8.0.2, you can use Window Functions with Frames

Comment: Also, share your `Create Table` statement(s), giving details of indexing defined (if any)

Comment: I think you have a typo in your original query, instead of `AND`, it should be `Where`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya updated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Subqueries, a "Self-Inner-Join" can be more efficient. Try the following instead:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(t1.date), 
  MONTH(t1.date), 
  SUM(t2.quantity) 
FROM tb AS t1 
JOIN tb AS t2 
  ON t2.date BETWEEN (t1.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND t1.date 
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(t1.date), MONTH(t1.date)
```